# jQuery add CSS attribute without markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site that produces markup on the fly(Wordpress3.5) so I can't directly add data-tooltip to the html. Therefore I am trying to add the attribute via Javascript. In the provided fiddle I added some example HTML, can someone please help with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkdh8/) in trying to successfully add 'tooltip' to the markup or explain why my script is currently not working? Thanks.

```
// set the tooltip content
jQuery('li#menu-item-75 a:hover:before').prop('tooltipText', 'w00t');
jQuery('li#menu-item-75 a:hover:after').prop('tooltipText', 'w00t');
```

Comment: Open console, _"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"_

Comment: You need to add the jquery library as well as set it up to the domReady event in the upper right hand dropdowns in jsfiddle...

Comment: No framework was chosen in your fiddle. When set to jQuery I see a yellow arrow appear on hover.

Comment: jQuery has no `:before` or `:after` selector. WHat are you trying to target?

Answer (score 0):

Use the data method (http://api.jquery.com/data/) to read and set data:

```
$("#myelement").data("tooltip", "my tooltip text");
```